# Add an email alias with unattended GPG key generation

Tags: shell-script, gnupg

I am generating GPG keys with unattended key generation as described at https://www.gnupg.org/documentation/manuals/gnupg/Unattended-GPG-key-generation.html :

```
gpg --batch --generate-key "genkeyconf"
```

with input file `genkeyconf` formatted as described by the manual.

I can manually add an email alias after key generation using `gpg --edit-key "$keyid" adduid`, but I do not know how to do it in an unattended way.

Supplying a second `Name-Email: $mail` or a comma- or space-separated list of mail addresses to the input for the batch key generation does not seem to do it. Also adding another group `Name-Real: ... Name-Email: ...` will not.

Looks as if the possibility that two or more UIDs are needed has been forgotten or ignored in the design of this unattended interface.

Comment: I haven't tested it but the manual (https://www.gnupg.org/documentation/manuals/gnupg/OpenPGP-Key-Management.html#OpenPGP-Key-Management) contains a `--quick-add-uid` which seems to allow adding a new uid to an existing key  in an unattended way.

Comment: I think this can do it. You will need to enter the password of the new key again, but better than nothing. Why don't you write an answer?

Comment: Because `--batch` is so limited, I'm trying to do unattended key generation with `--command-fd` and `--status-fd`.  I'm asking a question [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1571752/gpg-unattended-automated-key-generation).