# gpg: Unattended/Automated Key Generation

Tags: bash-scripting, gnupg

The `--batch` option to `gpg` is limited to generating a key with a single subkey.  For anything more complicated, I am trying to use `--command-fd` and `--status-fd`.  The problem I face is that I am unable to find a way around the popup requesting I input a password.  Here is a simple test case:

```
#!/bin/bash

gpg2 --homedir ./gpg-test --passphrase "apassword" --status-fd 1 --expert --full-gen-key --command-file <(cat <<-EOF 
        8
        S
        Q
        1024
        0
        My Name
        me@my.com
        mycomment
        EOF
)
```

Despite the `--passphrase` switch, when the script reaches the point just before the `EOF`, instead of recognizing the switch, a popup appears.  I tried adding apassword just before `EOF`, but that fails.  When I try  `--pinentry-mode loopback`, which is documented in the `man` page (gpg2 v.2.1.11), I get an error:

```
gpg: setting pinentry mode 'loopback' failed: Not supported
[GNUPG:] ERROR set_pinentry_mode 67108924
gpg: agent_genkey failed: Not supported
Key generation failed: Not supported
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to leave this question because there are probably others with similar confusions.  As it turns out, the method I am trying is working in v.2.2.4.  So despite the documentation, it's not supported in 2.1.11.

On top of this, the proper and easiest way to do unattended key generation as of 2020, is to use [--quick-generate-key and --quick-add-key](https://serverfault.com/questions/818289/add-second-sub-key-to-unattended-gpg-key#962553).  The method I was trying to use, with `--command-fd`/`--status-fd`, is only necessary for more complicated tasks.  For example, [there are many kinds of signatures on keys](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/159088) and `--quick-sign-key` only offers the simplest.  For more complicated cases `--edit-key` may be necessary, in which case my above approach is appropriate.